# Create like status bar design in android

Tags: android, android-button

I convert website to mobile app.

**In webview these are 5 states,**

[image]

I am already try with buttons. But wrap content not work in buttons.

If I add background with clickable, it increase the button height.

so I can`t alignment properly.

[image]

**I want look like first picture?. any body answer my question?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with TextView and a parent layout instead of Buttons. The pattern might be this following:

**@layout "buttons bar":**

```
<!-- use a parent layout (the grey bar) -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/background"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/grey_gradient" />

    <!-- inside the 4 states (textview with padding) -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="Draft"
        android:id="@+id/text_draft"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:color="@color/black" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="Confirmed"
        android:id="@+id/text_draft"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:color="@color/black" />

     <!-- ... other texts ... -->

 </LinearLayout>
```

Then, your gradient grey background on LinearLayout (the grey bar), you have to use a drawable (as you can see in the example above). It might be something like this:

**@drawable "grey_gradient.xml":**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:angle="90"
                android:startColor="@color/grey_one"
                android:endColor="@color/grey_two"
                android:type="linear" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Finally, set all the colors into **colors.xml**.

Hope you will get the expected result.